# Why won't colorbox add my class to the carousel images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/m2barfho/3/

Been stumped on this, asked a similar question, but not this exact one.

I have the following function,

```
$('#colorbox').each(function() {
  var imgs = $('img');
  imgs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('cboxPhoto')) {
      var img = $(this);
      if (img.width() < 500 && img.height() > 1000) {
        img.addClass('relative');
      } else {
        img.removeClass('relative');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I am essentially stating for the div #colorbox, if the `<img>` has the class of 'cboxPhoto' then run the each() function to add the class of "relative" to the `<img>` if the image width is greater than X and it's height is greater than X. This function works fine when the HTML is already statically placed in. However, these images are dynamically generated.

These images are not manually placed into the HTML, these images are uploaded via an upload module. This is the HTML markup below of when the DOM creates when 'colorbox'loads --'colorbox' creates the id of 'cboxLoadedContent' and generates that image.

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 13px; left: 0px; position: absolute; width: 11169px; height: 1536px;">
  <div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 1536px; width: 11169px;">
    <div>
      <div id="cboxTopLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTopCenter" style="float: left; width: 11169px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTopRight" style="float: left;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 1536px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 11169px; height: 1536px;">
        <div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 9999px; overflow: auto; height: 768px;">
<img class="cboxPhoto" src="img/designations/3.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 370px; height: 3453px; float: none;">
          <img class="cboxPhoto" src="img/designations/1.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 250px; height: 250px; float: none;">
          <img class="cboxPhoto" src="img/designations/4.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 300px; height: 1922px; float: none;">
        </div>
        <div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left; display: block;"></div>
        <div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left; display: block;">image 3 of 6</div>
        <button type="button" id="cboxPrevious" style="display: block;">previous</button>
        <button type="button" id="cboxNext" style="display: block;">next</button>
        <button id="cboxSlideshow" style="display: none;"></button>
        <div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
        <div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
        <button type="button" id="cboxClose">close</button>
      </div>
      <div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 1536px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxBottomLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div id="cboxBottomCenter" style="float: left; width: 11169px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxBottomRight" style="float: left;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; max-width: none; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

THE PROBLEM:

As I mentioned above, these images are not manually placed onto the page they are generated by 'colorbox'-- which is created AFTER the DOM is loaded? I tried a few different `.load` and `.ready`, that did not work? Is there some callback function I can set for it to add the class after it detects the image has been created and then run my each function that precedes it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".preview").colorbox({
        rel: 'preview',
        onComplete: function(){
        $('#colorbox').each(function() {
          var imgs = $('img');
          imgs.each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('cboxPhoto')) {
              var img = $(this);
              if (img.width() < 500 && img.height() > 1000) {
                img.addClass('relative');
              } 
            else {
                img.removeClass('relative');
              }
            }
          });
    });
        }
    });
});
```

needed to ad onComplete function and then run my proceeding function.

http://jsfiddle.net/UFtrK/522/